# Android: Animated Door

Tags: android, animation

i want to do open door animation when user enter the system. For example in the picture below: [image]

when user presses enter, doors should open.

But how can i do that? According to my searches, maybe sequential images can solve it. But any idea would be great. Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find **Rotation 3D demo** from android demo.

In this it uses **180 degree.**

But for your problem create **two** efferent images of doors
one for left side door.
one for right side door.

set animation to **90 degree.**

hope this will help you.

EDIT: API demo links...

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/animation/Transition3d.html

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/animation/Rotate3dAnimation.html

Comment: Thank you i forgot the api demo actually, and i found very useful codes :)

Comment: @jakobiyem if you found something then please share it can help others also.

Comment: @varun actually i don't remember :( because i found a lot of examples in the demo code and i couldn't do animated door..